# i need to print 1-100 in javascript such that each number carries a grade(100-A, 99-A etc)

Tags: javascript, loops

HEY guys i want to print 0-100 in javascript such that

80-100 will carry the grade A and so on

e.g

```
0 - 35 - F 
36 - 40 - E 
41 - 49 - D
50 - 70 - C 
71 - 85 - B
86 - 100 - A
```

so far i've been able to come up with this

```js
let score = 100;

for (let i = 100; i >= 0; i--) {
  if (score >= 86) {
    console.log(i + '-' + 'A')
  }
  
  if (score <= 86 || >= 60) {
    console.log(i + '-' + 'B')
  }
}
```

Comment: What is preventing you from completing this?

Comment: `score <= 86 || >= 60` should probably be `score <= 86 && score >= 60` because you want it both not either.

Answer (score 2):

You could create a grades array, specifying the max and min scores for each grade.

You can then use Array.find to get the grade.

```js
const grades =  [ 
    { name: 'F', min: 0,  max: 35 },
    { name: 'E', min: 36, max: 40 },
    { name: 'D', min: 41, max: 49 },
    { name: 'C', min: 50, max: 70 },
    { name: 'B', min: 71, max: 85 },
    { name: 'A', min: 86, max: 100 }
]

function getGrade(score) {
    const grade = grades.find(grade => score >= grade.min && score <= grade.max);
    return grade ? grade.name: "Not found";
}

console.log(getGrade(35))
console.log(getGrade(89))
console.log(getGrade(65))

console.log("Showing grade list:");
let scores = Array.from({ length: 21}, (v,k) => (+k)*5);
scores.forEach(score => console.log(`Score: ${score}, Grade: ${getGrade(score)}`))
```

Comment: this is the solution.                                                                                                                  for (i=100; i>=0; i--){
    if(i <= 100 && i >= 86){
        console.log( `${i} - A`);
    }else if(i <= 85 && i >= 71){
        console.log( `${i} - B`)
    }else if(i <= 70 && i >= 50){
        console.log( `${i} - C`)
    }else if(i <= 49 && i >= 41){
        console.log( `${i} - D`)
    }else if(i <= 40 && i >= 36){
        console.log( `${i} - E`)
    }else{console.log( `${i} - F`)}
}